# Angular BehaviorSubject returns initial value when subscribing after setting next value

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I do have the following service:

```
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

  private _schema = new BehaviorSubject("User");
  currentSchema = this._schema.asObservable();

  setSchema(schema: string) {
    this._schema.next(schema);
  }
}
```

When i subscribe to the observable and change the value after subscribing, everything works fine, but when i do subscribe in another component AFTER changing the value, i receive the inital value intead of the new set value.

So when i subscribe to the observable in `ngOnInit()` and setting a next value in the same component, it works. But i want to receive that next value in another component which is created later.

I am using the service like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.testService.currentSchema.subscribe(x => {
      console.log('DETAIL >> ' + x);
    });
}
```

I have no clue why this is happening, as the sense of BehaviorSubjects is getting the value even after subscribing.

Comment: Sounds like your components are using different instances of the service. Is the service set in the providers array in either of the components? Can you provide a live demo in stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, the service is set in the providers array of the `app.module.ts`

Comment: Can you provide a live demo.

Comment: Your code should work with the `BehaviorSubject`, the problem might be with the `setSchema()` function being called after the `ngOnInit()` runs

Comment: I just set up a demo project, where everything works fine. I have no clue where my problem is. The one component must use another instance of the service, but i don't know why that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be in the component itself. I never though of that being a problem of the component, so i tried everything from creating new services, a whole new testapp etc.

When i tried to create a new component to use the service there, it worked. I could not really figure out what was causing the issue in the old component, i just copied the code 1 to 1 to the new component, but it worked all of a sudden.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **[AsyncSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/asyncsubject)** instead of BehaviorSubject like this

```
private _schema = new AsyncSubject();
```

The AsyncSubject is aSubject variant where only the last value of the Observable execution is sent to its subscribers

this is an example  [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mdinuk)

so your code will be

```
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

  _schema = new AsyncSubject();


  setSchema(schema: string) {
    this._schema.next(schema);
  }

   getSchema(){
      return this._schema;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but this has nothing to do with my problem.